# Is there any technique can quickly expand one set of cell chromosomes?

Tags: molecular-genetics, chromosome, gene, epigenetics, dna-replication

Assume a cell type is very scarce while isolated out and hard to expand in vitro, and I wanna have more of its chromosomes, is there any technique , in vivo or in vitro or ex vitro, any would count, that allows me to quickly expand the amount of those chromosomes?

I know it sounds weird but just some curiosity~

Thanks